# @Html.EditorFor doesn't show initial value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm developing a MVC project. In form I send data from controller to view. When I inspect it in browser input value is shown. But not in view. The code is below:

This is the input element:

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequiredAmount, new
                {
                    htmlAttributes = new
                    {
                        @class = "form-control",
                        @type = "number",
                        @min = "0",
                        @step = "0.1",
                        @value = "0",
                        @readonly = "readonly"
                    }
                })
```

And this is the Model:

```
 public class DirectionAllowRequest
 { 
     public decimal RequiredAmount { get; set; }
 }
```

Also I use automapper if it is esential. But when I debug id I show the value is set.

It works for input type text but not for number. I think decimal value makes this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What value do you see in the view? Did you try removing `@value = "0",` ?

Comment: Yes. In view it is shown as empty input.

Comment: depends also what control is used by the editor for, do you have a `decimal.cshtml` in your `Shared/EditorTemplates` folder ?

Answer (score 0):

The ideology of MVC requires the developer to set default values in the Controller and not in the View.

You can set the value in the View's(e.g Index.cshtml) corresponding action like below:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new DirectionAllowRequest() { RequiredAmount = 0 };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for attention. Of course, I did it.

Comment: Hi @FarhadAzadaliyev, after doing that, still not working?

Comment: Hi @Rena. Unfortunately, no.